# Does localization commute with taking radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

> Let $A$ be a ring, $S\subset A$ a multiplicative set, and $I\subset A$ an ideal not intersecting $S$. For any ideal $J$, let $r(J)$ denote the radical of $J$. Is $S^{-1}r(I) = r(S^{-1}I)$?

Certainly $S^{-1}r(I)$ is generated by elements of the form $\frac{x}{s}$, where $x^n\in I$. This implies that $\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)^n = \frac{x^n}{s^n}\in S^{-1}I$, so $\frac{x}{s}\in r(S^{-1}I)$. This shows that $S^{-1}r(I)\subseteq r(S^{-1}I).$

The other direction seems less clear. Certainly $r(S^{-1}I)$ is generated by elements of the form $\frac{x}{s}$ where $\frac{x^n}{s^n}\in S^{-1}I$. It isn't clear to me that this implies that $\frac{x}{s}\in S^{-1}r(I)$.

Comment: There are two more elegant ways that I think will work but let's just crank it out. We know $x^n/s^n = y/t$ for some $y \in I$, $t \in S$. So there some $u \in S$ s.t. $utx^n = us^ny$. That doesn't give you $x^n \in I$ but it does tell you that $(utx)^n \in I$.

Comment: @Hoot This is the way I worked it, and then noticed that you had already indicated this method in your comment.  What are some more elegant ways to show this, though?

Comment: @user26857 That's a special case! It sounded like the claim was $S^{-1}(\bigcap_i I_i) = \bigcap_i S^{-1}I_i$ and I had always sort of assumed this wasn't so.

Comment: @Hoot Localization commutes with finite intersections, but in general, it doesn't commute with arbitrary intersections (Eisenbud Commutative Algebra Exercise 2.5): 

Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $S$ be the set of nonzero elements of the polynomial ring $k[x]$ in one variable. Then 

$$S^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{a\in k}(x-a)\right)\neq \bigcap_{a\in k} S^{-1}(x-a)$$

Comment: $\def\I{\mathcal{I}}$Geometric remark: this result allows to prove that $$\label{1}\tag{1}\sqrt{\tilde{I}}=\widetilde{\sqrt{I}}$$ as quasi-coherent ideal sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec} A$, where given an ideal sheaf $\I$ on a ringed space $X$, the *radical sheaf* $\sqrt{\I}$ is defined to be the sheafification of the presheaf $U\mapsto\sqrt{\I(U)}$. It is easy to verify $(\sqrt{\I})_x=\sqrt{\I_x}$, $x\in X$. From this last equality plus $S^{-1}\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{S^{-1}I}$, equation \eqref{1} follows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\frac{x}{s}\in r(S^{-1}I)$, so $\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{s^n}\in S^{-1}I$ for some $n$ and therefore $\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{s^n}=\frac{i}{t}$ for some $i\in I, t\in S$

Then $ux^{n}t=us^{n}i\in I$ for some $u\in S$, so $(uxt)^n\in I\implies uxt\in r(I)$ and therefore

$\hspace {.25 in}\displaystyle \frac{x}{s}=\frac{uxt}{uts}\in S^{-1}(r(I))$

Comment: In the last step of the argument, you need $uts \in S$. Why is that true? We know that $u, t \in S$. What about $s$?

Comment: @MathManiac Since $\frac{x}{s}\in S^{-1}A$,  $s\in S$ and $x\in A$.

Comment: Are you using the fact that $ux^nt = (uxt)^n$? I haven't taken algebra in a while so I can't remember if that's a theorem or something.

Comment: @Smash It's definitely not a theorem and this equality does not hold in general. But if $ux^n t \in I$ then $(uxt)^n = u^{n-1}t^{n-1} ux^n t \in I$.

Comment: @user84413 sorry for the late comment but I still don't understand why $uts\in S$. You said $\frac{x}{s}\in S^{-1}A$ with $s\in S$ and $x\in A$ but how do you even know that $s\in S$? The only thing we assume is that $s^n\in S$ right?