# Question about nilradicals and localization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Suppose we have a commutative ring $A$ with identity. Is it true that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then we have
$$ \mathcal{N}( A_{\mathfrak{p}}) \simeq  \mathcal{N}(A)_{\mathfrak{p}} \quad ? $$
Where $\mathcal{N}$ denotes taking the nilradical. Furthermore, is it still true that if we replace localization at $\mathfrak{p}$ with localization at the multiplicative set generated by some non-nilpotent element $f$?

Comment: Could you correct your notation? Right now, both sides of the equality are the same and I am sure you did not mean that.

Comment: Sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the nilradical is the set of all nilpotents, or the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) of the zero ideal $\sqrt{(0)}$. In general, [localizing commutes with taking radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847139/does-localization-commute-with-taking-radicals). In particular, localizing at a particular prime will of course work as well.

To see this, let $S \subset A$ be a multiplicative subset. Consider $\frac{x}{s} \in S^{-1}(\sqrt{(0)})$. then $a^n=0$, so $(\frac{a}{s})^n=0 \in S^{-1}(A)$, so it is also in $\sqrt{S^{-1}(0)}$.

The first answer in the link provides the other direction, but it is again from the definition.

Answer (score 12):

Besides referring to more general results, you can also prove the statement directly.

Suppose $a/s$ is nilpotent in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. This means $a^n/s^n=0$, for some $n>1$, so $ta^n=0$ for some $t\in A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$. Hence also $(ta)^n=0$ and therefore
$$
\frac{a}{s}=\frac{ta}{ts}\in\mathcal{N}(A)_{\mathfrak{p}}
$$
The converse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: Why does $ta^n = 0$ imply that $(ta)^n = 0$?

Comment: @Smash $(ta)^n=t^na^n=t^{n-1}(ta^n)$